# How to redirect to a page on submit?

Tags: php, html, form-submit, hubspot

I am trying to redirect users who click a submit button to a seperate page, while simultaneously submitting their data.

I have tried to use `<a>` tags around the div but this doesn't change where my submit location goes (refreshes the page).

I am on Hubspot COS, but this should be relatively the same...

Here is my html:

```
<div class="hs_submit">
<div class="hs-field-desc" style="display: none;"></div>
<div class="actions"><input class="hs-button primary large" type="submit" value="Submit">
```

Comment: why you are not using `form` tag in html ?

Comment: ^ there's that ? This is after all what a form does, it submits data and redirects!

Comment: The HubSpot COS generates most of the functionality, all of the submit is handled through their system.

Answer (score 2):

You're not using `<form>` and you should.

```
<form action="newpage.php" method="get">
    <input class="hs-button primary large" type="submit" value="Submit">
</form>
```

You can also use `POST` as opposed to `GET`, depending on your needs. Change `newpage.php` to whichever page you want to direct the user to. That page should also be able to process or handle the input from the form.

Answer (score 0):

In Hubspot's COS, use a "landing page" when using a form rather than a "site page".

On the landing page edit page, immediately under where you select the form is the option to either direct to a new page (and you then enter in where to direct) or provide an inline edit thank you.